# how to take error logs in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql am change following settings for postgresql.conf file.But,logging file is display empty.I want to log all error returned from postgresql.

```
log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog,syslog'

logging_collector = on

log_directory = 'pg_log'

log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'

syslog_facility = 'LOCAL7'

syslog_ident = 'postgres' log_min_duration_statement = 0    

log_statement = 'all'
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following:

```
log_min_error_statement = error
log_min_messages = error
```

Don't forget to run `pg_ctl reload` after changing `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe ,Am change this settings also,but not.some other things to  change other than postgresql.conf settings changes

Comment: I don't understand. Did it not work? Did you run `pg_ctl reload`?